# How can I open slack modal during slack workflow execution step?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I am currently working on slack app with custom workflow step which is used to get some data from user during execution using modals,

I can do that using built-in forms from workflow builder like in the attached image.

[Built in workflow form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzQeS.png)

However my form is more interactive and requires input fields to be changed based on user selection, to do that I am trying to consume https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/modals API with custom workflow step.

My question is, do I have any chance to call open modal API, during custom workflow execution step: https://api.slack.com/events/workflow_step_execute ?

So far I failed to identify what can I use as `triggerId`  during workflow step execution.

Thank you in advance and I do understand my question is complex, so will be happy to provide more information.

Comment: Hi @Gevorg, wondering what alternative you took to acheive your objective. Can you share?

Comment: I just send a message with a button and after user clicks on a button it triggers modal to be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to trigger a modal from within a Workflow. Workflow Builder currently doesn't support conditional interactivity either. Sorry I don't have better news. On the plus side, Workflow Builder is going to see some significant upgrades this year!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's one of the biggest requests and I hope slack can build on it soon.
A solution that is usually used for this case is to send an ephemeral message in the channel where the workflow was opened, with a button to open the modal.